# Calling nmake with link options

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nmake

I am calling `nmake` from `VS2015 X64 Native Tools`. I am getting this output:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\bin\scan3d-capture.exe @C:\Users\HF220~1.HEL\AppData\Local\Temp\nm231F.tmp
```

After this, I am getting link errors telling me that I am linking X86 with X64 libs. I want to link against X64 and I am trying to build X64 version. but it seems that from this linking option `/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32'` the problem exists.

how can change link option when calling `nmake`?

Comment: it really depends on what is in your makefile

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Thank you very much.. it seems like that .. this link command was written inside the makefile but I did not realize that